# Intergrating Firebase with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, reactjs, firebase, django-rest-framework

So I have a Django back-end with a Firebase database and a React front-end. I want to POST data from the React to the Django which will Post to Firebase (I know i can do it all in JS to Firebase but i figure it might help more to have a python back-end for the future). I see tutorials using Django Rest Framework and I have been able to get that work but it uses SQLite3 and not Firebase. How can i implement Firebase into Django Rest Framework?

Comment: Django does not officially support firebase -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/

Comment: You edited the question to make it an entirely different question.  Ask a new one.  Also, graphics.h is not a standard 'C' library.  So the answer to your question depends on the graphics library you are trying to use, which you don't idenitfy.